# APScheduler - job not executed

Tags: apscheduler

I'm new to APScheduler and testing it before implementing it in a larger scope.

I have created the code below, but somehow my functions are never called when I use add_job with `trigger='date'`. If I use `trigger='interval'`, then everything works fine.

I also tried to play with `run_date` param, with no luck.

Any idea about what could be wrong ?

Apscheduler is version 3.0.3

Many thanks in advance :)

```
def my_listener(event):
    if event.exception:
        print('The job crashed :(')
    else:
        print('The job worked :)')

def test():
    print("{}  ok ".format(datetime.now()))


def myFunc(content, img):
    print("{} - content={}|image{}".format(datetime.now(), content, img))
    myfile = open("scheduler.log", "a")
    myfile.write("{} - content={}|image{}".format(datetime.now(), content, img))
    myfile.close()

def main():
    jobstores = \
        {
            'default': SQLAlchemyJobStore(url="postgresql+psycopg2://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}".format(db_user, db_password, db_host, db_port, db_database))
        }

    executors = \
        {
            'default': ThreadPoolExecutor(20),
            'processpool': ProcessPoolExecutor(5)
        }

    job_defaults = \
        {
            'coalesce': False,
            'max_instances': 3
        }

    scheduler = BackgroundScheduler(jobstores=jobstores, executors=executors, job_defaults=job_defaults, timezone=utc)
    scheduler.start()
    CURR_DATE = datetime.strptime(datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%Y%m%d%H%M'), '%Y%m%d%H%M')
    JOB_DATE = CURR_DATE + timedelta(minutes=1)
    uid=uuid.uuid4()
    newjob = scheduler.add_job(myFunc,
                                trigger='date',
                                args=['content data', 'image data'],
                                kwargs=None,
                                id=str(uid),
                                name='test' + str(uid),
                                misfire_grace_time=5,
                                coalesce=False,
                                max_instances=1,
                                next_run_time= JOB_DATE,
                                jobstore='default',
                                executor='default',
                                replace_existing=True)

    print("Added - {}".format(newjob))
    scheduler.add_listener(my_listener, events.EVENT_JOB_EXECUTED | events.EVENT_JOB_ERROR)
    scheduler.print_jobs()
    while True:
        sys.stdout.write('{}\n'.format(datetime.now())); sys.stdout.flush()
        sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 4):

Problem is that you are using
next_run_time= JOB_DATE,
instead of run_date=JOB_DATE,

another option is declaring your trigger and passing it as a parameter to add job like this:

```
trigger = DateTrigger(run_date=start_date)
newjob = scheduler.add_job(myFunc,
                            trigger=trigger,
                            args=['content data', 'image data'],
                            kwargs=None,
                            id=str(uid),
                            name='test' + str(uid),
                            misfire_grace_time=5,
                            coalesce=False,
                            max_instances=1,
                            jobstore='default',
                            executor='default',
                            replace_existing=True)
```

another problem with your code is that while you made your scheduler timeaware you are using an unaware datetime

```
CURR_DATE = datetime.strptime(datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%Y%m%d%H%M'), '%Y%m%d%H%M')
JOB_DATE = CURR_DATE + timedelta(minutes=1) #this is unaware
```

try declaring your date this way:

```
import pytz
import datetime

job_date = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.UTC) + datetime.timedelta(minutes=1)
```